# Why is only the last record of my .txt file being inserted into my AVL Tree while I can insert records via command line?

Tags: java, insert, text-files, java.util.scanner, avl-tree

I'm working on a project that takes a .txt file and reads a list of records and inserts them into an AVL tree.  It appears to read the records from the file fine but only inserts the last record in the file into the tree.  There is also a command-line interface that allows the user to add records to the tree.  This interface works fine and inserts additional records.  Here is a sample of the .txt file and the code.

```
.txt file:
# Names for database
# Don't modify this file
# These are comments
# File description:
# ID, FirstName LastName Age
1 Aeris Lopez 18
2 Sofia Yeong 33
```

Method for reading .txt file and inserting into the tree:

```
public static void readRecords() throws FileNotFoundException {

        int idNumber = 0;
        String fName = "";
        String lName = "";
        String age = "";
        String line = "";

        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("test.txt"));

        inFile.nextLine();
        inFile.nextLine();
        inFile.nextLine();
        inFile.nextLine();
        inFile.nextLine();


        while (inFile.hasNext()) {

            idNumber = inFile.nextInt();
            record.setIdNumber(idNumber);

            fName = inFile.next();
            record.setfName(fName);

            lName = inFile.next();
            record.setlName(lName);

            if (inFile.hasNext())
            age = inFile.next();
            else
                age = "";
            record.setAge(age);

            tree.insert(record);
            System.out.println(record);
        }

        inFile.close();
    }
```

Command-line user interface method:

```
public static void commands() {

//        commandList();

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        Record record = new Record();
        int choice = console.nextInt();
        int idNumber;
        String age;
        int count = 0;
        String lName = "";
        String fName = "";


        switch (choice) {
            case 1: //Allows user to search for record by last name.
                System.out.println("Enter the last name to search for.\n");
                findLName = console.next();
//                AVLTree.findLastName(record);
                commands();
                break;

            case 2: //Allows user to search for record by first and last name.
                System.out.println("Enter the first and last name to search for.\n");
                findFName = console.next();
                findLName = console.next();

                commands();
                break;

            case 3: //Allows user to add a new record.
                System.out.println("Enter the id number, first name, last name, and age" +
                        "of the record to be added.\n");
                idNumber = console.nextInt();
                record.setIdNumber(idNumber);

                fName = console.next();
                record.setfName(fName);

                lName = console.next();
                record.setlName(lName);

                age = console.next();
                record.setAge(age);

                RecordUtils.tree.insert(record);
                System.out.println("Record #" + idNumber + " has been added.\n\n\n");
                RecordUtils.tree.printTree(AVLTree.root);

                commands();
                break;

            case 4: //Prints out the total number of records in the AVL tree.
                System.out.println("There are " + RecordUtils.tree.countNodes() + " records in The Amazo Name " +
                        "Storage Program Shadow Magic 2000 System\n\n\n");

                commands();
                break;

            case 5: //Prints out the user command list.
                commandList();
                commands();
                break;

            case 6: //Prints out the author of the code.
                System.out.println("This code was created by Toby Myers.\n\n\n");
                commands();
                break;

            case 7: //Allows the user to exit the program.
                System.out.println("Exiting The Amazo Name Storage Program " +
                        "Shadow Magic 2000 System.");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default: //Notifies user if invalid input is entered.
                System.out.println("Invalid Input");
                commands();
        }


    }
```

I am more than happy to provide any more additional info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your static method readRecords is adding information to a `Record` object but since the object is not created in the method you are overwriting the information in the same instance for each row.

The solution is to create a new object for each row

```
  while (inFile.hasNext()) {
        Record record = new Record(); //<-- This is needed

        idNumber = inFile.nextInt();
        record.setIdNumber(idNumber);

        fName = inFile.next();
        record.setfName(fName);

        lName = inFile.next();
        record.setlName(lName);

        if (inFile.hasNext())
        age = inFile.next();
        else
            age = "";
        record.setAge(age);

        tree.insert(record);
        System.out.println(record);
    }
```